# Why is a batsman out, when the impact is outside off, on an umpire's call?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating

Can a batsman be given out when the ball impacts outside the line, having pitched outside off and with an indication that it would have hit the stumps?

The original decision of the umpire on the field was Out, and the batsman made a referral to the Umpire Decision Review System.

Comment: Was the batsman playing a shot? What was the decision on the field? Did the umpire or the players instigate the review?

Comment: Yes, he was playing a shot, and the on-field decision was out. The batsman went for the review. There were two reds apart from the impact which was outside off.

Comment: Could you give more details of the specific incident you're referring to? As UDRS was available, I'm guessing it was a major match.

Comment: Yes it was during the 1st test between SL and Ind in Kolkatta few days ago. But I could not remember which instance though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ball neither needs to pitch nor strike inline, if it was coming from outside off into the stumps, in order to give Out, Leg before wicket.

This is the basis of the original decision. The two flags for Pitching - inline and Impact - inline only some green if they are actually inline, even though that is not always necessary for Leg before wicket. As long as the third and important flag (Wickets - hitting) is green, the correct decision is Out.

See Law 36, part 1.2 for the pitching and part 1.4 for the contact.

Note that this assumes "the striker has made no genuine attempt to play the ball with the bat". As this aspect of the law comes outside the scope of UDRS, it must be assumed the umpire decided no genuine attempt to play the ball was made.

Comment: Thanks @Nij. In order to clarify what you said, you mean that even though the impact is green when the other two **(pitching outside off and hitting the stumps)** are red, it'll be given out. If so, is it because of the umpire's call or the ball hitting the stumps?

Comment: @Kulasangar If the on-field umpire thinks the batsman wasn't playing a stroke and the ball wasn't leg side, then it's only the 'hitting' part of the DRS system that matters. If that says hitting, it's out, if it says missing it's not out, if that says umpire's call, then they keep the original decision.

Answer (score 1):

@Kul if he was playing a shot, for him to remain out (i.e. On field call stays):

- Ball needs to pitch in line with stumps or outside off stump (or can also be umpire's call, i.e. half pitching on leg stump, half pitching outside leg stump)
- Impact must be in line with the stumps or umpire's call
- The ball must hit the stumps or be umpire's call

If no shot was offered, the only change is:

- Impact is irrelevant
- The ball still cannot pitch outside leg stump (to avoid negative bowling creating a wicket)

I haven't actually seen this incident, but those are the scenarios. Hope this answers your question.